# Advantage of implementing my own slideshow gallery in GWT?

Tags: gwt, slideshow

I am asking myself about coding my slideshow gallery with GWT. Should I justify the implementation of a such functionality assuming that GWT provides bundle image (and other optimizations related to images and cache) ? If yes, should it be interesting to use new functionalities that offers HTML5 and CSS3 ? Tkx.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it definitely makes sense to do a slideshow gallery in GWT.  You can build in your own customizations that aren't available in pre-packaged slideshows such as pre-fetching the next image in the background, using ResourceBundle/ImageBundle to get a list of thumbnails which is handy for random selection.  It's not that interesting since GWT makes it really easy.


You can also do image transitions (animate) to make it look nice... This is all built into GWT.

Comment: Hello Pavel, it is time for me to develop this slideshow. Your answer is very interesting, would you have more information or a tutorial about it, because it is a little difficult to start from scratch without an example (I have not seen a lot about gwt slideshow on the web)... tks